# Calculating signals in stock trading

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, finance

### Pre-description

I am analyzing stock prices.

- The **spread** value is the value of one pair.
- A pair is two stocks, like **Amazon_Tesla**.
- If the **signal is 1**, it means the stock must be sold.
- If the **signal is 0**, means that the stock must be bought.

[image]

### Inputs

1. std values: float
2. spread: list or pandas series

### Outputs

1. Signal-1
2. Signal-2

### How do the signals change?

Signal changes according to *spread* and *threshold value*. In this example, the threshold value is the standard deviation (value=1). In index # 2, we sell amazon shares and buy tesla shares.  The spread must be expected to exceed the std value for the first trade to begin. Signal values change as in the sample data.

### Result

What is the easiest way to get outputs like the example using inputs?

To access sample data:
https://gist.github.com/birdalugureren/05ea6995a9f31478599e9c062e9cd452

Comment: please also post the expected output.

Comment: To achieve what? I don't understand what you are asking. Do you need an algorithm, a program, help with a program? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Input values: std and spread values
Output values: signal1, signal2

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to describe a function for each signal using the `standard deviation` value in relation to the `spread values` to produce the points where the stock action will turn. After that, use [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to forward fill the spaces where there is no change in the stock operation.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'index': {i:i for i in range(20)},
  'spread': {0: 0.4, 1: 0.6, 2: 1.1, 3: 0.8, 4: 1.5, 5: 0.6, 6: -0.01, 7: -1.4,
  8: 0.1, 9: 0.4, 10: 1.4, 11: -1.5, 12: -0.4, 13: 0.3, 14: 0.6, 15: 1.2, 16: 0.7,
  17: -0.3, 18: -0.8, 19: -1.9}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

std_dev = 1

func_sig1 = lambda x: 1 if x > std_dev else 0 if x < 0 else np.NAN
func_sig2 = lambda x: 1 if x < -std_dev else 0 if x > 0 else np.NAN

df["Signal-1"] = df["spread"].map(func_sig1).ffill()
df["Signal-2"] = df["spread"].map(func_sig2).ffill()

print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```
    index  spread  Signal-1  Signal-2
0       0    0.40       NaN       0.0
1       1    0.60       NaN       0.0
2       2    1.10       1.0       0.0
3       3    0.80       1.0       0.0
4       4    1.50       1.0       0.0
5       5    0.60       1.0       0.0
6       6   -0.01       0.0       0.0
7       7   -1.40       0.0       1.0
8       8    0.10       0.0       0.0
9       9    0.40       0.0       0.0
10     10    1.40       1.0       0.0
11     11   -1.50       0.0       1.0
12     12   -0.40       0.0       1.0
13     13    0.30       0.0       0.0
14     14    0.60       0.0       0.0
15     15    1.20       1.0       0.0
16     16    0.70       1.0       0.0
17     17   -0.30       0.0       0.0
18     18   -0.80       0.0       0.0
19     19   -1.90       0.0       1.0
```